# How to keep highlight the last selected item in gridview?

Tags: android, gridview, highlight

I want to highlight the last selected item in my gridview. I mean by highlighting that I want to keep that orange frame that is popping up when you touch an item in the gridview by default.

Picture:

[image]

How can I add that frame manually or how can I keep that for atleast the next click?

Comment: Is there your screen changes while clicking on your gridView? If yes than you have to manage clicked item's position to highlight when grid view created.

Comment: Yes, I swap two selected gridview items. I want to highlight the first one or the keep the frame that is shown onclick. Is there any easy way to do it, maybe a method of the gridview/gridview child?

Comment: No, I think there is no method that can do as you are saying. You have to manage it manually.

Comment: So thats the question, how could I do that?